# Selenium Webdriver Java can't click on <a> link

Tags: java, selenium

I have an issue, my test case is as follows:

1. Open the website `whois.net`
2. type sitename and click Search button.

But my test is not able to make a click. I don't understand why?

Here is my code (Maybe you can advise something for me):

```
 WebElement registerButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#hdSearch span input a"));

 registerButton.click();
```

I got the next error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div#hdSearch span input a"}
```

Comment: I don't know what the HTML of the page you're looking at is, but the whois.net page I get doesn't have that, if you wanted the element to search, you'd want this selector: div#searchBox table tbody tr td:first-of-type a

Comment: Try like this `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#domain_search + a"))`

Comment: Yep, that works, Thanks guys

Comment: But what to do if element does not have ID?

Answer (score 0):

a first look a the whois.net helps to know to need clearer selector for you link, something with XPATH like this:

`/html/body/form/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a`

so please try:

```
 WebElement registerButton = driver.
            findElement(
                    By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a")
                );
 registerButton.click();
```

Comment: I am trying to find another element on page using your example, but id doesn't work for me . Here is my code
     WebElement elContactEmail = 
  
  
  
  
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/#page/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/ul/li/a.mail"));
   String contactEmail = elContactEmail.getText();
   System.out.println(contactEmail);

Answer (score 0):

To locate the **Search** button and click on it you can use the following code block :

```
WebElement registerButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#searchBox a"));
registerButton.click();
```